# change notification default icon in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, onesignal

I'm using onesignal and trying to change the default notification "bell icon" in the app

so after generating my icon from [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_ac_unit)
and name it to `ic_stat_onesignal_default` and add it into `/android/app/src/main/res/` folders, after that I uninstall the app and rebuild it,
and add it to payload notification "API"

```
small_icon: 'ic_stat_onesignal_default'
```

**But** still, I got the **default** one (**Bell**) as a notification icon :(

is there any step I forget?

here's my **AndroidManifest.xml** file if you wondering

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.salonyUser">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationAccentColor.DEFAULT" android:value="0F0F0F" />
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

- 

**EDIT**

After added
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_onesignal_default" /> // I choose mipmap-xxxhdpi icon size for test. :)
```

I just was wanted to test if firebase meta-data will work or not and Actually it's work and I got the icon I want!!
have anybody explanation to this!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to also set both `.setSmallIcon()` and `.setLargeIcon()` in the `NotificationCompat.Builder`

See this answer for additional info:
[How to set the app icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34225779/how-to-set-the-app-icon-as-the-notification-icon-in-the-notification-drawer)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an Android developer, but where should I add this builder? I'm using a `react-native-onesignal` and it's not mentioned about this before! So could you help in this case where should I achieve it?

Comment: Hey again :) @thomasciv, I just updated the Q, Can you please check the Edit section above?

Comment: @OliverD Either one would probably have to be registered in the manifest file. You might try something like this to get the it working without firebase: `com.onesignal.messaging.default_notification_icon` for the name.

Comment: Yes, its work :D but I'm just  why with firebase also work

Comment: Possibly wherever you are referencing the `android:name` from the manifest file, it will tie back to the correct icon regardless of whether you're actually using Firebase. The `name/value` pair should be all that's important. As long as you have a meta-data tag in the manifest.

Comment: Fair enough you're right, and you should use the name `ic_stat_onesignal_default` otherways will not work and will appear the bell default icon :)). Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Set icon in the *NotificationCompat.Builder* using *.setSmallIcon()* for smaller icon and *.setLargeIcon()* for large icon.

Comment: As I said before to @thomasciv where should I put these things as I'm using react native onesignal?